Why can’t my Synology NAS access the internet 100% of the time?
I just bought a Synology DS923+ NAS with an SPF port, which I connected to the 10G port on my Deco BE85.
My internet provider supplied me with a router that I configured in bridge mode. My Deco router is working well; I have internet everywhere, both on Wi-Fi and Ethernet.


I notice there's a problem when I do the "setup router."

Every other time, the DNS check passes, but 100% of the time I get a warning on "Checking network environment."
My NAS only manages to connect to the internet intermittently. When I use nslookup in SSH, it works 50% of the time.
I have absolutely no issues with other devices on my network. I can always access the NAS via QuickConnect without any problems.
Do you have any idea where the issue might be coming from?

Have you tried setting the DNS to automatic or manually pointing it at the Deco at 192.168.68.1? Thing is, the Synology may be having a hissy fit because the DNS servers are outside the local network, so it can't resolve local hosts.

I had the exact same problem since we got Fibre and an ORBI router. Couldn't access the internet, so no time synchronisation, no updates, etc. After reading here I enquired with my ISP about a static IP - they charge 33c each day for a static IP which is $120/year - so that was not acceptable.
After some playing around I found the problem could be solved by going to Control Panels > Network > Network Interfaces > select Lan1 > Edit > change from 'use manual configuration' (for a static IP in my own network to ‘Get network configuration automatically (DHCP)’).
The NAS now connects to the internet just fine.

Funnily enough AFTER it was working again I was the next day able to aggregate the two Ethernet ports again into one link, and set the assigned local IP as a static local IP for it - so basically I'm back to where I started from but now it works. It seems the ORBI did not like to take over the old setup but needed to provide it's own IP address for whatever reason.

I called my fiber provider. I had a shared internet IP, they switched it to a dedicated IP, and now I no longer have any issues.
